# spring boot 2.0 @Value does not work in @Configration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm leaning spring boot 2.0, I use @Value annotation as same as early release, but it's not work in @Configration annotation.

application.yml

```
test: 
    a: test
```

TestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment()
                  .getProperty("test.a"));//got test
    }
}
```

TestConfigration.java

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfigration{
    @Value("${test.a}")
    String a;


    @Bean
    public Bean getBean(){
        System.out.println(a);//there!!!the a is NULL!!!  WHY?

        return new Bean();
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController{
   @Value("${test.a}")
   String a;

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String test(){
      return a;//got test
   }
}
```

why?

Comment: I understand this is the code where it works, can you, please add code example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @ailav  at TestConfigration.java  the a's injection is failed

Comment: Are you aware of your missing `class` keywords?

Comment: sorry my fault @ImpulseTheFox

Comment: Okay, I created an example project with exactly that code, and it prints "test" twice, and not "test" and `null`, so I cannot reproduce (it works for me). I also used Spring Boot 2.0.0. So that means the issue must be somewhere else in your code or you're having some wrong assumption.

Comment: @unclosable, running the same code with Spring Boot 2.0.0. works for me too. Please, add your project structure and/or `pom.xml`, because if there's a problem it's not in that's added to the question right now.

Comment: we run spring boot 2.0 in production for a few weeks. Nothing wrong with the above code. Change to @Value("${test.a:it_really_works}"). If that breaks either something is wrong with component scanning (did you turn that on) or something else in your project.

Comment: yes , this problem is caused by my carelessness @JillesvanGurp

Answer (score 0):

Emmmm ... there is no problem in the questions's code , it works.

I ignored a warn log when spring boot start:

```
2018-03-26-21:21:27 WARN  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor] - Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'TestConfigration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
```

it's because I register a org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer with @Bean but miss static keywords, it's necessary if a implementation of BeanFactoryPostProcessor register and @Value is used in same configuration class.

I don't know it and I used to be wrong for too long，I didn't find it out because the db configuration and mybatis configuration is not in same class  in my past project.

thanks to @ailav and @Impulse The Fox ,and forgive my weird English:)